# Could not find module `Yesod'

Tags: haskell, yesod

I have the following code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, QuasiQuotes, MultiParamTypeClasses,
             TemplateHaskell, OverloadedStrings #-}

module Simple where
import Yesod
data HelloWorld = HelloWorld

mkYesod "HelloWorld" [parseRoutes|
/ HomeR GET
|]

instance Yesod HelloWorld

getHomeR = defaultLayout [whamlet|Hello World!|]

withHelloWorld  f = toWaiApp HelloWorld >>= f

main = warpDebug 3000 HelloWorld
```

If run it in GHCI, it runs normally:

```
Ok, modules loaded: Simple.
*Simple> main
Application launched, listening on port 3000
```

But if run it as:

```
wai-handler-devel 3000 Simple withHelloWorld
```

the console reports an error:

```
pshuvaev@pshuvaev-K73SV:~/works/haskell/yesod/SimpleSite$ wai-handler-devel 3000 Simple.hs withHelloWorld
Attempting to interpret your app...
Compile failed: 

Could not find module `Yesod'
Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
```

What could be the problem? Yesod is set and it displays in the output of `ghc-pkg list`.

Comment: I'm not familiar with `wai-handler-devel` does it look at the local project's cabal file?

Comment: What about just `runhaskell Simple.hs`?

Comment: I do not have cabal file.. In the directory is only one file - Simple.hs. With runhaskell I try to run later. But on different, just installed operating system (Ubuntu 12.04) and the just installed haskell-platform and yesod this error does not occur.

Comment: if I run runhaskell, it works fine:                          
    `pshuvaev@pshuvaev-K73SV:~/works/haskell/yesod/SimpleSite$ runhaskell Simple.hs                              
    Application launched, listening on port 3000`

Answer (score 2):

On Unix systems remove `~/.ghc` directory and run:

```
ghc-pkg --global recache
```

On Windows systems (just suggestion) remove `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\ghc` and also recache from the command line (as Admin):

```
ghc-pkg --global recache
```

**Not sure about Windows!** Please check!