# Getting "Could not find module `Yesod'" when I try to run first example from Yesod book

Tags: haskell, yesod, haskell-stack

I know this seems a duplicate to [Could not find module `Yesod'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14589358/could-not-find-module-yesod), but unlike that user, `ghc-pkg list` does not show `Yesod` in its output on my computer, they didn't seem to be using `stack` (I am, and I'm not sure if that means I don't need to worry about `ghc-pkg list`), and additionally, the answer (code) to that question did not help my situation.

The *Yesod Book* has an [example](http://www.yesodweb.com/book/basics#basics_hello_world) that I've been trying to get to work for several hours now. I'll reprint it here

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings     #-}
{-# LANGUAGE QuasiQuotes           #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell       #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies          #-}
import           Yesod

data HelloWorld = HelloWorld

mkYesod "HelloWorld" [parseRoutes|
/ HomeR GET
|]

instance Yesod HelloWorld

getHomeR :: Handler Html
getHomeR = defaultLayout [whamlet|Hello World!|]

main :: IO ()
main = warp 3000 HelloWorld
```

I'm using the latest 64-bit Ubuntu OS. The problem I consistently run into is that `runhaskell hello-world.hs` will time-and-time again return

```
hello-world.hs:6:18:
    Could not find module `Yesod'
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
```

Likewise when I add a `module` name to the file and try loading it with `stack ghci hello-world.hs`. I'm using `stack` to build things, and I've tried many different iterations of `stack new` (with yesod templates), `stack init`, and `stack build`'s left and right, with `stack update`'s here and there for good measure, and even a few `cabal install`'s, along with the entirety of [the Yesod quickstart guide](http://www.yesodweb.com/page/quickstart), all to no avail, and all within the proper directories.

When I use Yesod templates with `simpleSQL`, the template site loads properly, and moreover a much larger project that I'm working with, [Snowdrift](https://git.gnu.io/snowdrift/snowdrift/tree/master), runs as well (albeit as a site, using `stack exec yesod devel` and not a `runhaskell FILE` command; but still, it works, and I've tried the exact same build process for handling the `hello-world.hs` file above.

I feel like this problem has a simple solution that I'm missing, but I've tried and tried, and searched all over, and I just haven't come across an answer.

Thanks a bunch for taking the time to help me out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not find module \`Yesod'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14589358/could-not-find-module-yesod)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`runhaskell hello-world.hs` and `ghc-pkg list` will default to using the global system and user package databases (that is, the ones cabal-instal normally uses), and not the snapshot and project-specific ones used by stack (see also: [Why doesn't stack add packages to the ghc package database?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31393189/2751851)). You should instead use `stack runghc hello-world.hs` and `stack exec -- ghc-pkg list`. The stack commands ensure the GHC tools use the appropriate package databases (and also the appropriate versions of GHC, in case you ever need a `stack setup` to use a different GHC than the one installed system-wide).

Answer (score 1):

Your results may vary, but this worked for me (on 13 Jan 2018):

- Mac OS 10.13.2 (High Sierra)
- Searched Hackage for Yesod, found 1.4.5 at https://hackage.haskell.org/package/yesod-1.4.5/docs/Yesod.html
- stack install yesod-1.4.5
- Got dependency error with suggestion to add conduit-extra-1.1.13.1 to extra-deps (in ~/.stack/global/stack.yaml).
- Tried again; got more dependency errors, with the result being that I ended up with:
- extra-deps: ["gtk-mac-integration-0.3.4.0","conduit-extra-1.2.3.2","conduit-1.2.13","streaming-commons-0.1.18","typed-process-0.2.1.0","unliftio-core-0.1.1.0"] (You might get different recommendations; I just followed the ones I got. Note: I already had the gtk-mac-integration extra-dep before I started).
- successfully stack-installed yesod-1.4.5
- stack runghc helloworld.hs
- success!

In hindsight, it should seem obvious that module "Yesod" would not be found it it had not yet been installed. I usually work within a stack-created Haskell project, and in that case would have taken the usual steps to ensure the dependency was present. I usually don't run applications with "stack runghc".